# Limit background image to body only

Tags: html, css

I have background but when I make footer the background image of the body spans to the footer; how can I limit this background only to the body? Here is my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #282828;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #FF7F50, #23A6D5, #FF7F50);
  background-size: 400% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>Posted by: asds</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
     someone@example.com</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see a background image? If you don't want the background of the body to show through, set a background on the footer.

Comment: The footer is part of the `body`, so if you want a different background for the footer, you'll have to define a background for the footer. Alternatively, instead of putting the background on the `body`, make a container for the `body` content within the `body` that does not include the footer code and apply the background to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your footer a background color. The `<body>` defaults to white so try adding

```
.footer {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

> Of course, you'll notice in the example below that the background again at the bottom and edges. You can, as APAD1 mentioned, change your html structure, or remove the default margin from `<body>` and adjust your footer some more

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #282828;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #FF7F50, #23A6D5, #FF7F50);
  background-size: 400% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

.footer {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>Posted by: asds</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
     someone@example.com</a>.</p>
</div>
```